# Given 8 bits in a byte, how to find all the possible numbers resulting from flipping of one or more bits in this byte

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, pascal

I'm using a byte variable to store color combinations. The value of each bit position represents one color. Thus, by turning one or more bits in the byte on, a combination of colors can be persisted to a memory variable.

I am looking for the algorithm to generate all the possible combinations of [one or more bits of the byte] being in a state of either on or off, with the exception of all bits off ie. 0.

```
const
  GREEN = 1; //binary 1
  RED = 2; //binary 10;
  BLUE = 4; //binary 100;
  ORANGE = 8; //binary 1000;
  VIOLET = 16; //binary 10000;
  YELLOW = 32; //binary 100000;
  CYAN = 64; //binary 1000000;
  WHITE = 128; //binary 10000000;
```

This is what the byte looks like with all 8 bits turned on:

[image: The byte]

Comment: Just a for loop.

Comment: All possible numbers representable by 8 bits aka 1 byte are 0-255. If you want to exclude 00000000 then it’s 1-255. This is basic binary arithmetic. Or am I missing something here? What exactly is the question?

Comment: Not sure I follow, the amount of combinations is `(2^8) - 1` (minus the all-zero) and the numbers are exactly all numbers from `1` to `2^8 - 1`. `2^8` is `256`.

Comment: @DennisTraub Ok.. now I see. There are 255 possible combinations resulting exactly in values 1 - 255. I think that should have solved my problem. Whew! Thanks!

Comment: Great. I’m happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte can be thought to represent an unsigned number 0..255. These are represented by the values `0000_0000` and `1111_1111` respectively. Each bit represents a specific power of two. Let's number the bits from left to right with an index, `b_i`. Then the bits represent a value `v_i = 2 ^ b_i` when they are on, and zero when they are not on. The number is then the addition of all `v_i` values.

Back to your question, the only thing you need to do is to create all byte values except value `0000_0000`. You can create a counter that starts with 1 (`0000_0001`) and then counts to 255. The resulting variable will loop through all possible values. Generally you can, in a programming language, just declare a byte variable to do this (in Pascal: `color: byte;` [it seems](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Byte)), and then use `color = color + 1;` or `color++` if your language supports this. Both the declaration, the addition and the check for `<= 255` can be put in a `for` loop of course.

A trickier question is how to combine the different colors into a new one? Especially the inclusion of `WHITE` is vexing. Quite often we simply use Red Green and Blue (RGB), although nowadays professionals work with other color spaces.

Comment: "number the bits from left to right" For the bits to represent a power of 2, the numbering starts at 0 and goes from right (LSB) to left (MSB).

Comment: That depend on the *bit order* of the byte, generally big endian is used within specifications. And, pretty often, 1 based indexing is used as well, in which case the bits are numbered `b8` to `b1` with `b8` the highest order bit. However, that does make the calculations unnecessary complex, so I decided to use `b0` to `b7` instead. My answer, my ordering :P